# How can i make that this program fills in the Form?

Tags: python, selenium

Recently i have began with Selenium in Python with Chromium Webdriver, but it doesn't fill in the Login Screen, what did i wrong? I think it has to be with the "find_element" function. Here's my Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time


driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://instagram.com")
print(driver.title)

input_username = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/main/article/div[2]/div[1]/div/form/div[2]/div/label/input")
input_username.send_keys("lowity")

time.sleep(5)

input_paswd = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/main/article/div[2]/div[1]/div/form/div[3]/div/label/input")
input_paswd.send_keys("password")

time.sleep(5)

button_login = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/main/article/div[2]/div[1]/div/form/div[4]/button")
button_login.click()

time.sleep(5)

time.sleep(10)
driver.quit()
```

And the console has no error output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to wait for element being clickable in order to click it. The best way is to user the `WebdriverWait()` function with `until(EC.element_to_be_clickable)` Here is the updated code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = 'C:\\chromedriver.exe')

driver.get("https://instagram.com")
print(driver.title)

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/section/main/article/div[2]/div[1]/div/form/div[2]/div/label/input"))).send_keys("lowity")

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//html/body/div[1]/section/main/article/div[2]/div[1]/div/form/div[3]/div/label/input"))).send_keys("janosch2005")

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/section/main/article/div[2]/div[1]/div/form/div[4]/button"))).click()

driver.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks!, that worked for me, but i don't understand why i have to wait? Can you explain it or send me an link?

Comment: @Lowity please upvote and accept my answer then :) You have to wait because the login page is rendered via `JS` which means it does not instantly appear on the page - it appears after the `JS` got executed. The script will click it as soon as the element will be clickable and rendered, After X seconds - in that code 10, when there will be no element clickable with that `XPATH` it will raise and `exception`